# Generate public & private get in Angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cryptography, ecdh

I have a nodeJS server, on which I can generate public & private keys in this way

```
let algo = 'prime256v1';
const bob = createECDH(algo);
bob.generateKeys();
const bobPublicKey = bob.getPublicKey('hex');
const bobPrivateKey1 = bob.getPrivateKey('hex');
```

this node js code will generate a public key & private key of length 130 & 64

I want to do the same in Frontend also, My frontend app is angular 10.

Tried to do it in UI like this

```
const keyPair = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      {
        name: 'ECDH',
        namedCurve: 'P-256',
      },
      true,
      ['deriveKey', 'deriveBits']
    );
```

And then convert the both CryptoKey into hex format

This generate public key & private key of length 182 & 184

but the length of the key generated from `nodeJS` and `crypto.subtle` are different.
Is there any way to generate same ECDH('prime256v1') in UI with crypto.subtle or any library ?

Comment: The crypto/NodeJS code generates the raw keys (regarding the public key, the uncompressed key is returned: 0x04|x|y), while the WebCrypto/JavaScript code returns private and public keys, each encapsulated in a CryptoKey. If you want the raw keys, the (probably) easiest way is to export them as a JWK with [`exportKey()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey) and extract from the JWK the private key and the x and y coordinates of the public key, respectively. Note that in the JWK Base64**url** is used as encoding.